# SQL not exists to find some issues

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

I'm practicing some SQL (new to this),
I have the next tables:

```
screening_occapancy(idscreening,row,col,idclient)
screening(screeningid,idmovie,idtheater,screening_time)
```

Im trying to creating a query to search which clients watched all the movies in the "screening" table and show their ID(idclient).

this is what I written(which doesn't work):

```
select idclient from screening_occapancy p where not exists 
 (select screeningid from screening where screeningid=p.idscreening)
```

I know it's probably not that good so please try to explain also what am I doing wrong.

P.S My mission is to use not/exists while doing it...

Thanks!

Comment: No need for that `DISTINCT` in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically fine, although the `select distinct` is unnecessary in the subquery:

```
select p.idclient
from screening_occapancy p
where not exists (select 1
                  from screening s
                  where s.screeningid = p.idscreening
                 );
```

Notes:

- You can select *anything* in the `exists` subquery.  Selecting a column is misleading.
- Use table aliases and use them for all column references, particularly in a correlated subquery.
- If you are designing the tables, I would advise you to give the primary key and foreign key the same name (`screeningid` or `idscreening`, but not both).

EDIT:

If you want clients who watched all movies, then I would approach this as:

```
select p.idclient
from screening_occapancy p
group by p.idclient
having count(distinct p.screening_occapancy p) = (select count(*) from screening);
```

Comment: Thanks , but my+your'e query dosent work (even though there is a client who watched everything...)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you count the number of movies in the screening_table, load it into a variable and check the results of your query results against the variable?

load number of movies into variable (identified by idmovie):

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT(idmovie)) FROM screening INTO @number_of_movies;
```

check the results of your query against the variable:

```
    SELECT A.idclient, 
    count(DISTINCT(idmovie)) AS number_of_movies_watched,
    FROM screening_occapancy A
    INNER JOIN screening B
    ON(A.idscreening = B.screeningid)
    GROUP BY A.idclient
    HAVING number_of_movies_watched = @number_of_movies ;
```

If you want to find all clients, that attended all screenings, replace idmovie with screeningid.
Even someone relatively new to MySQL can get his head around this query. The "not exists"-approach is more difficult to understand.